# Why GCC can not find the header files in includes folder?

Tags: c++, opengl, makefile, linker-errors

I am trying to include glad.h  in my main.cpp using `#include <glad/glad.h>` using this makefile ~

```
CC      := g++
CFLAGS  := -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -g

BIN     := bin
SRC     := src
INCLUDE := include
LIB     := lib

LIBRARIES   := -lglad -lglfw3dll

ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
EXECUTABLE  := main.exe
SOURCEDIRS  := $(SRC)
INCLUDEDIRS := $(INCLUDE)
LIBDIRS     := $(LIB)
else
EXECUTABLE  := main
SOURCEDIRS  := $(shell find $(SRC) -type d)
INCLUDEDIRS := $(shell find $(INCLUDE) -type d)
LIBDIRS     := $(shell find $(LIB) -type d)
endif

CINCLUDES   := $(patsubst %,-I%, $(INCLUDEDIRS:%/=%))
CLIBS       := $(patsubst %,-L%, $(LIBDIRS:%/=%))

SOURCES     := $(wildcard $(patsubst %,%/*.cpp, $(SOURCEDIRS)))
OBJECTS     := $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

all: $(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    -$(RM) $(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE)
    -$(RM) $(OBJECTS)


run: all
    ./$(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE)

$(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CINCLUDES) $(CLIBS) $^ -o $@ $(LIBRARIES)
```

but everytime i get this error...

```
g++    -c -o src/main.o src/main.cpp
src/main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: glad/glad.h: No such file or directory
 #include <glad/glad.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
mingw32-make: *** [<builtin>: src/main.o] Error 1
```

every header file is present in the include  folder still it is not working.
please help...
how to fix this 
if there any other type of errors in make file please point it out...
Thanks.

Comment: Well, where is the `glad.h` header file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `make`is invoking a built-in rule to compile your source files to object files but that rule knows nothing about your `CINCLUDES` or other variables.  From the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-C_002b_002b_002c-rule-to-compile)...

> **Compiling C++ programs**
>
> n.o is made automatically from n.cc, n.cpp, or n.C with a recipe of
>   the form ‘$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c’.

The simplest solution would be to add `$(CINCLUDES)` to `$(CPPFLAGS)`

```
CPPFLAGS += $(CINCLUDES)
```

Comment: Thanks G.M. for the solution. but now there is a new problem related to libraries linking